# missing firmware navi10_mes.bin for module amdg

Tags: radeon, initramfs, amdgpu, firmware

I try run below command on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k $(uname -r)
```

I get:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

So where I can get this file (navi10_mes.bin) ?
BTW. CPU is AMD Ryzen 7 4800h and AMD RADEON integretared gpu

Comment: This is only a warning not an error. As long your system is working ignore it, until the firmware is integrated in package linux-firmware.

Answer (score 8):

You can get most firmware files from the upstream linux-firmware repository:

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/

This person also maintains a GitHub repository of firmware which AMD have made available via ROCm and the proprietary driver, but not uploaded to `linux-firmware` yet:

https://github.com/Umio-Yasuno/unofficial-amdgpu-firmware-repo

However, the file `navi_10.mes` does not exist in either of these.

We can see this is a genuinely used firmware file with Linux Kernel commit:

- [drm/amdgpu/mes10.1: load mes firmware file to CPU buffer](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=298d05460cc459aef9d5ae0b022e2e27f5eaac34)

I checked driver `amdgpu-pro-20.50-1234664-ubuntu-20.04` which contains `amdgpu-dkms-firmware_5.9.10.69-1234664_all` which doesn't have the file either.

It seems this file is not publicly available at this time?

Leaving this answer as a Community Wiki so someone can update it when the file appears.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did:

Uninstall amdgpu-install

```
sudo amdgpu-install --uninstall
sudo apt-get purge amdgpu-install
```

Download the latest drivers from AMD website and install

```
sudo dpkg -i ./amdgpu-install_5.4.50401-1_all.deb
```

Reinstall amdgpu with this command

```
sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=workstation --vulkan=pro --opencl=legacy -y --accept-eula
```

Reboot. Problem solved!

Comment: Which problem was solved this way?

Comment: Missing firmware for amdgpu. It happend after kernel update

Comment: If you are not using a specific hardware, that message is not a problem.

Comment: After kernel upgrade my gpu AMD Radaen RX580 dit not work properly and could not change my resolution.

Comment: "not a problem" -> great, then it doesn't have to show up when every single user is patching.