# Possible missing firmware -amd?

Tags: firmware

On running sudo apt upgrade I constantly get the following which slows down the upgrade:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-52-lowlatency
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/yellow_carp_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/sienna_cichlid_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
```

The thing is - I believe I do not even have amd! Only Intel!

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.25.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.98.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-50-lowlatency (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Precision 5720 AIO
```

How do I get this to not happen?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Missing firmware that you don't need anyhow is not a problem. And I do not think it slows down the upgrade. Often users like to keep all their firmware files up to date, needed or not, so as to eliminate the missing firmware messages.

What I find odd in your question is the file names. Doing an upgrade just now, I did not get those missing firmware messages and I do not have those files, but I do have similar files, for example:

```
doug@desk-jj:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263296 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_ce.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263424 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_me.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268592 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_mec2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268592 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_mec.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263424 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_pfp.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  25344 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_rlc.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33792 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_sdma1.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33792 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/cyan_skillfish2_sdma.bin
doug@desk-jj:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 160256 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_asd.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263296 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_ce.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  84980 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_dmcub.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263424 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_me.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268592 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_mec2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268592 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_mec.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263424 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_pfp.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  45368 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_rlc.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 135424 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_sdma.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1792 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_toc.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 542976 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/vangogh_vcn.bin
doug@desk-jj:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 160256 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_asd.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263296 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_ce.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    772 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_gpu_info.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263424 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_me.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268592 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mec2.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 268592 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mec.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 263424 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_pfp.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  43952 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_rlc.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33792 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_sdma1.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33792 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_sdma.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 267970 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_smc.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184512 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_sos.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  33536 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_ta.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 400832 Aug 31 04:11 /usr/lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_vcn.bin
```

EDIT: There are other questions mentioning some of the same missing files. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315776/missing-firmware-navi10-mes-bin-for-module-amdg), for example

Comment: I answered somewhere that one can install upstream `linux-firmware` to get rid of these messages.

Comment: Well, the fact is it IS slowing down my upgrading. It keeps going over and over the missing firmware and not progressing. I only have Intel. I suspect that I may have inadvertently installed amd drivers at one stage. amdgpu must relate to hardware, no? So, I suppose the question is how do I remove it? If that is what I need to do! ? Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04

Kernel Version: 6.2.0-1010-lowlatency (64-bit)

Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Graphics Processor: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 530
Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
Product Name: Precision 5720 AIO

Answer (score 0):

I have the same recurring problem, but I have an AMD GPU that works fine despite these warnings.
What really piss me off is :

- the length of the update which pass from 3 seconds to 5-10 minutes just to generate the initrd with all these "missing" firmware error loops
- the fact that I don't understand why I should have ~ 250 Mo of multiple firmware present locally even if I do not have the corresponding hardware physically installed on my machine ?
  I'd really appreciate some answers other than "it's only a warning" or "may be  someday you'll need it" (just kidding ;-)
  TIA

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1328123)